# in jQuery how to access an id that is loaded via Ajax after the initial DOM

Tags: jquery

I am loading a modal in a page that the user can then interact with.

```
var global_id=$(this).data('global-id');
var other_global_id=$(this).data('other-global-id');
var comment=$('#pairing-comment').val();  // <- this is not working!!!
```

but I'm not sure how to access this properly. I've tried scoping it but maybe this can't be done although I think it can me. Here it is console:

[image]

so this is happening in response to a user event so it's definitely happening later.

```
$(document).on('click','#comment-submit', function(){
    arc_eh.event_handler.submit_pairing_comment.call(this);
  });
```

Comment: Make sure to execute the code after the ajax is successful.

Comment: so it's being captured in response to an event so it's definitely happening later

Comment: you probably need to set you comment var after printing the ajax content on the page. Where is you ajax call code?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't to do with scope, it's to do with the fact that when you try to assign your variable, the `$('#pairing-comment')` element doesn't have a value yet.

You should assign the variable in the success function of your AJAX call to make sure the value is ready.

Comment: the other variable have correct values based upon 'on' call in the update

Comment: I am just going to delete this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can only access it after the AJAX request completed successfully. It's not enough to do it after the click event because it may not loaded by that time. Example:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '',
            data: {},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {

                // Access it here!
            },
            error: function() {}
        });
```

Comment: all of that has been done and am able to succesfully access other variables associated with this